# Function argument list doesn't match function template (function template is made for passing stack allocated array)

Tags: c++, arrays, function-templates

I made function template to pass stack-allocated array as parameter, which is shown below:

```
struct Pos {
    int row;
    int col;
    Pos(int r, int c) {
        row = r; col = c;
    }
    Pos() {
        row = 0; col = 0;
    }
};

template <int R, int C>
void traverse(int (&matrix)[R][C], bool (&visited)[R][C], Pos& target) {
          // code inside function
};
```

I tried to call function with arguments inside 'int main()' like below:

```
int matrix[rowSize][colSize];
bool visited[rowSize][colSize];

Pos target;
target.row = 0;
target.col = 0;

traverse(matrix, visited, target);
```

When I try to run the code with g++, it gives me error:
`no instance of function template "traverse" matches the argument list.`

Any suggestions or corrections?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to pass
`traverse(&matrix, &visited, target)`
`traverse(*matrix, *visited, target)`

I knew it won't work but I was just desperate.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve]? If I fill in the blanks it seems fine. https://godbolt.org/z/beW3qn3M3

Comment: `int matrix[rowSize][colSize];` -- `bool visited[rowSize][colSize];` -- What are `rowSize` and `colSize` declared as?  If they are not constant expressions, then this is not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: My guess is that `rowSize` and `colSize` are not constant values known at compile-time, only at runtime. If so, then the arrays are [variable-length arrays, which are [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/), and AFAIK you can't take a reference to a VLA (but you can take a pointer). If you need an array sized at runtime, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @RetiredNinja  I used non-constant expression for 'rowSize' and 'colSize' variable while I am referencing to a VLA. So it wasn't the problem of the blank I guess.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  You are right. After I fixed it as constant expression, it worked!

Comment: @RemyLebeau   Thanks for explanation! Didn't know VLA concept well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be maybe from rowSize and colSize declaration , which arent deduced correctly at compiling time , if you have rowSize and colSize as integers it would cause an error as they should be constants ,so i guess you need to add in your main : constexpr int rowSize and constexpr int rowSize (i hope this helps)

Comment: Definitiely helped. Realized VLA needs constant expression in array size to reference them.

Comment: @Hyun If the sizes are constants at compile time, then the arrays won’t be VLAs anymore